# I get “lapacke.h: No such file or directory” On CentOS

Tags: c++, centos, installation, lapack

I have the same problem like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034284/i-get-lapack-h-no-such-file-or-directory-although-i-installed-liblapack-dev). I googled for hours but I don't know what I should install to have  the `#include<lapacke.h>` header file.

I tried this one `lapack-3.2.1-4.el6 RPM for x86_64`for my CentOS 6.8.
But still I have the same problem.

Thanks for any guide.

Comment: Is it possible to copy the header file to a directory and give the address by `-I` ?

Comment: I got the package from here ( http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapack.tgz ) and gave the header file address by `-I /path_to_folder/lapack-3.7.0/LAPACKE/include`. It solved the problem someway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is a silly observation but I see that your include `#include<lapacke.h>` instead of `#include<lapack.h>`. Another thing,

No special header is required, Only usual headers will be there.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
```

Then, try to use the normal functions, and dont do `#include<lapacke.h>`.

Comment: lapacke is not the same as lapack. In some linux distributions they even come bundled as different system packages. When using the C interface to lapack you do need to do `#include<lapacke.h>`